# How reload angular2 component?

Tags: c#, angular

I need this because my aplication components are using `templateUrl` generated by c# controller and when i change the permissions of a user, the components need to be reloaded.

Today im logout a user that make permissions change and calling `location.reload`, this is working great, but it's not the best way.

Old ago i was using `Compiler.clearCache()` but now this not work to me, any idea that what i can do to improve this ?

**Details**: Im using angular with lazyLoad routes.

**Version**: 4.2.5.

Comment: The best approach is to create a service and wrap the browser window object in a function and then inject it in you component and use location.reload on the window object. So far that was the best approach that I found.

Comment: _the components need to be reloaded_ - how are they loaded? do you use `loadChildren`?

Comment: @Maximus yes, i'm using loadChildren.

Comment: so do you want a router to reload every component for the current route and reinitialize them?

Comment: @Maximus yes, exactly this.